# more syntax-aware navigation in vim

Tags: vim

I have a good amount of code which looks like this:

```
rule requestIntHoleTemplate {                                            
    constr:HoleCall;
    y:PrimitiveIntRange;
    :IntRangeHole(constr, y);                                            

    modify {
        emit("Request template IntRangeHole\n");                         
    }                                                                    
}
```

I'd like to skip over the entire block in vim, not just to the next empty line as `}` does. I can accomplish it with `$%`, but that wouldn't work if I'm on an empty line preceding the block. I suppose I could alias `}{j$%j`. Are there other navigation commands I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `]]` and friends, but they only work if the opening brace is on its own line.

`]]` next beginning of block
`[[` previous beginning of block
`][` next end of block
`[]` previous end of block

Comment: Actually, they seem to work for the code I had. Thanks very much.

Comment: Unfortunately, they don't work with F# (a ML derivative) code though.